# What are these API_KEY and MAP_API_KEY in the example given in the official documentation of flutter_polyline_point

Tags: android-studio, flutter, google-polyline

Here is the example given in the Flutter document of **flutter_polyline_point**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:flutter_polyline_points/flutter_polyline_points.dart';

import 'Constants.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Polyline example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.orange,
      ),
      home: MapScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class MapScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MapScreenState createState() => _MapScreenState();
}

class _MapScreenState extends State<MapScreen> {
  GoogleMapController mapController;
  double _originLatitude = 6.5212402, _originLongitude = 3.3679965;
  double _destLatitude = 6.849660, _destLongitude = 3.648190;
  Map<MarkerId, Marker> markers = {};
  Map<PolylineId, Polyline> polylines = {};
  List<LatLng> polylineCoordinates = [];
  PolylinePoints polylinePoints = PolylinePoints();
  String googleAPiKey = Constants.MAP_API_KEY;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    /// origin marker
    _addMarker(LatLng(_originLatitude, _originLongitude), "origin",
        BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker);

    /// destination marker
    _addMarker(LatLng(_destLatitude, _destLongitude), "destination",
        BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(90));
    _getPolyline();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
          body: GoogleMap(
            initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                target: LatLng(_originLatitude, _originLongitude), zoom: 15),
            myLocationEnabled: true,
            tiltGesturesEnabled: true,
            compassEnabled: true,
            scrollGesturesEnabled: true,
            zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
            onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
            markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers.values),
            polylines: Set<Polyline>.of(polylines.values),
          )),
    );
  }

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) async {
    mapController = controller;
  }

  _addMarker(LatLng position, String id, BitmapDescriptor descriptor) {
    MarkerId markerId = MarkerId(id);
    Marker marker =
    Marker(markerId: markerId, icon: descriptor, position: position);
    markers[markerId] = marker;
  }

  _addPolyLine() {
    PolylineId id = PolylineId("poly");
    Polyline polyline = Polyline(
        polylineId: id, color: Colors.red, points: polylineCoordinates);
    polylines[id] = polyline;
    setState(() {});
  }

  _getPolyline() async {
    PolylineResult result = await polylinePoints.getRouteBetweenCoordinates(
        Constants.API_KEY,
        PointLatLng(_originLatitude, _originLongitude),
        PointLatLng(_destLatitude, _destLongitude),
        travelMode: TravelMode.driving,
      wayPoints: [PolylineWayPoint(location: "Sabo, Yaba Lagos Nigeria")]
    );
    if (result.points.isNotEmpty) {
      result.points.forEach((PointLatLng point) {
        polylineCoordinates.add(LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude));
      });
    }
    _addPolyLine();
  }
}
```

What is the difference between **API_KEY** and **MAP_API_KEY**? I am getting error there while trying to execute the example.

My requirement is to get the polyline points between two places in google map.
Kindly suggest me some examples to get the polyline drawn; if you have. I am getting problem in drawing the routes. Tried many examples but not getting it.

Answer (score 1):

To use google maps, you need to get an API key from the following link:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

This should be the `MAP_API_KEY` constant.

---

To use the direction api, you need to get an API key from the following link:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-api-key

This should be the `API_KEY` constant.

Comment: but both the keys are same no

Comment: if u use the same key what do u get?

Comment: nothing is happening if I am using the same key. Can you refer me any link on how to draw the polyline points on the map?

Comment: Do you already enable both API for your project from developer console? @sushreesomamohanty

Comment: @adadion yes I have

Comment: Peter's answer is definitely answer your question about the difference of MAP_API_KEY and API_KEY, and how to get them. You just need to paste it in your Constants class. Or, just paste it in your part of code `String googleAPiKey = pasteYourMapApiKeyHere;` and `await polylinePoints.getRouteBetweenCoordinates(
        pasteYourDirectionApiKeyHere,`